# Next.js Link to a component instead to page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning Next.js.
I am using `Link` to navigate through pages.

I want to load a React component instead of page.

Now I need to create the page and load the component:

> pages/about.js

```
import About from "../components/about/About";
export default () => <About/>
```

The page just loads the component. Can I just load the component itself in the `Link`?

Currently the `Link` looks like this:

```
<Link href="/about"><a className="nav-link">About</a></Link>
```

May be tweaking it little bit would do the job?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing the right thing already, but you could simplify it to one line:

```
export { default } from "../components/about/About"
```

Comment: The idea was not to have this page file at all. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe a `components` page, then dynamic routing to handle which component actually renders depending on the query passed to the route? https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing